# C2DM/Notification server other than google

Tags: android, notifications, android-c2dm

I would like to have a application which can receive notification/messages.Is it possible to have our own c2dm/notification server rather than using google gcm for our android device?

Comment: Well C2DM is depricated now, new is GCM.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own server. But be warned that will be hard and has scope for tons of bugs. There are many options apart from GCM that you can use. I have given a list of options in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14271725/1369222).