# Location client server tracking system

Tags: android, google-maps, android-location

I am making a project to track the school bus and want to sent the current bus location to parents' mobile device.

I am looking for a way to broadcast the location of one device to other devices in a pre-defined group.

Is it possible to communicate with all of the applications in the group without having to set up my own server/host/database?

it's possible to get location of another app device?

Comment: What do you mean "give me complete suggestion for my app?" You want us to write it for you?

Comment: i just wanted to help what should i do.?

Comment: Can you clarify what kind of help you need? As written it's not clear exactly what you're asking for help with.

Comment: I Get my current location and i want to use this location on my other Android device how sent ?

Comment: So, basically, you want to broadcast the location of one device to several other devices?

Comment: Yes sir exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use push notifications for this.

It is possible to use Firebase Cloud Messaging (which is the new replacement for Google Cloud Messaging) to broadcast a message to several devices. You can see a complete walkthrough [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple). You'll probably be particularly interested in [topic messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging). You could also [do the same thing](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging) with Google Cloud Messaging, but keep in mind that that service is deprecated.

There are other push notification services as well (for example, through Amazon Web Services).

This kind of a solution generally doesn't require that you maintain your own server.

Please also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271344/android-is-it-possible-to-broadcast-a-message-to-devices-without-using-google-c) for other options.

Comment: i am send bus location to php and i got the location on client app but how to notify client when bus come area of 100 meter of his home location location

Comment: @murleepatle You could get his house location from Google Maps API or something (or have the user enter the info) and compare it to the known bus location.